# Differential geometry and tori

Tags: differential-geometry

I am told curvature is a matrix** of types of curvatures for surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so it is logically presumable (and also is what I think I remember being told) it's a matrix for surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$. I have been 
told the surface $(\cos u, \sin u, \cos w, \sin w)$ for $u$, $w$ between $0$ and $2\pi$ has curvature zero, and someone else told me this is what is called the "flat torus." I'm trying to get a handle on the curvature matrix** by asking about the curvature of similar surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$: What's the curvature (matrix) of $(A\cos u, A\sin u, \cos w, \sin w)$ as a function of $(u, w)$ if $A$ is not $1$? (This surface isn't isotropic, unlike previous one.) What's curvature of:

- $(A\cos u, B\sin u, \cos w, \sin w)$?
- $(A\cos u, B\sin u, C\cos w, C\sin w)$?
- $(A\cos u, B\sin u, C\cos w, D\sin w)$?

I'm trying to isolate the various issues by first varying radii of circular 
cross sections and then moving from circular to elliptical cross sections.--Thanks, Rich Peterson

**Weingarten matrix

Comment: the **Gaussian's curvature** of the surface is the Weingarten matrix's determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question(s) there are two types of curvature: *extrinsic*, measured by how a surface "bends" in the surrounding Euclidean space, and *intrinsic*, measured by the angular defect of small geodesic triangles.

For a surface embedded in $\mathbf{R}^3$, extrinsic curvature at a point $p$ of $S$ may be measured by choosing a continuous unit normal field $\mathbf{n}$ in a neighborhood of $p$, taking sections of $S$ by planes through $p$ and containing $\mathbf{n}$, and finding the extreme reciprocal radii $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ of osculating circles of the resulting plane curves. These two numbers are the *principle curvatures* of $S$ at $p$ (well-defined up to a sign because $\mathbf{n}$ is only well-defined up to sign). They may be interpreted as the eigenvalues of the "second fundamental form" of $S$ at $p$, which I believe is what you're calling the "Weingarten matrix".

Intrinsic curvature is measured by the *Gaussian curvature*, a moderately complicated second-order differential expression in the "first fundamental form", a.k.a., the "metric (tensor)", of $S$. Gauss's *Theorema Egregium* ("run backward") implies that the Gaussian curvature of $S$ at $p$ is $\kappa_1\kappa_2$ (the product of the principle curvatures), which is nicely interpreted as the Jacobian of the Gauss map $\mathbf{n}:S \to S^2$.

All the results above hold for surfaces in $\mathbf{R}^3$, whose codimension is one. You're asking about surfaces in $\mathbf{R}^4$, for which intrinsic geometry is "just like in $\mathbf{R}^3$" but extrinsic geometry is not (because the normal space to $S$ at $p$ is two-dimensional).

Be that as it may, all four of your surfaces are intrinsically flat tori, i.e., are diffeomorphic to a product of circles and have Gaussian curvature identically zero. (Each is a "Riemannian product" of plane curves. Note incidentally that an *arbitrary* curve is intrinsically flat; differential geometry of curves -- curvature, torsion, etc. -- is all extrinsic.)

Your final ("most complicated") example is a product of ellipses of major/minor axes $(A, B)$ and $(C, D)$, whose extrinsic curvatures along the respective factors are not constant unless $A = B$ and $C = D$.

In case it matters, all four of your surfaces are *homogeneous* (if $p$ and $q$ are arbitrary points, there exists an "isometry" -- metric-preserving diffeomorphism -- carrying $p$ to $q$), but none of them is *isotropic* (if $v$ and $w$ are tangent vectors at some point $p$, there is generally no isometry of $S$ taking $v$ to $w$ unless $v = \pm w$, and even for the standard product of unit circles, the isotropy group of a point is finite).

If $A \neq B$ or $C \neq D$, the internal isometries of $S$ do not come from rigid motions of $\mathbf{R}^4$. This is probably the basis of your intuition that your surfaces are "successively less homogeneous".

Comment: I thank you, but for just for clarity, I didn't use the phrase "successively less homogeneous."

Comment: Yes; that use of quotation marks was meant to indicate informality, not verbatim attribution. :)